# Are all zeros of $g(n)$ one less than a power of 2?

Tags: prime-numbers

$f(n)$ is defined such that if $n = 2$, $f(n) = 1$, if $n$ is prime and $1$ more than a multiple of $4$, $f(n) = 1$, if $n$ is prime and $3$ more than a multiple of $4$, $f(n) = -1$, and if $n$ is composite,

$$f(n) = f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3),\cdots,f(a_m)$$

, where $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_m$ are the prime factors of $n$.
$g(x)$ is defined such that

$$g(n) = f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + \cdots + f(n)$$

I have written a [python program](https://repl.it/@DavidTyas/InsubstantialPrimeDesktopenvironment) that checks all integers from $2$ to $5000$ for $n$-values where $g(n) \le 0$, and the program found that there were no $n$-values where $g(n)$ was negative, and the $n$-values where $g(n)$ was $0$ were $3$, $7$, $15$, $31$, $63$, $127$, $255$, $511$, $1023$, $2047$, and $4095$.
However, I am aware that this is not a proof that the only zeros of $g(n)$ are one less than a power of $2$.

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $+$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: @joriki Er, no? $21$ is not writable in this manner, yet $f(21)=1$...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: You're right. It's the total number of prime factors $\equiv3\bmod4$ that's even if $f(n)=1$, whereas for the two-squares property the number of factors of each such prime must be even.

Comment: Your $g(n)$ is [OEIS sequence A037834](https://oeis.org/A037834). Your $f(n)$ is [OEIS sequence A112347](https://oeis.org/A112347).

Comment: This is quite suprising (to me). How did you come up with this? (I've checked it up to $2^{26}$.)

Comment: @joriki I've written up an answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Cool, $+1$!

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)=-1$ iff an odd number of the prime factors of $n$ are of the form $4k+3$ iff $n=2^m(4k+3)$ for some $m,k\ge0$.

Now, for an arbitrary $N$ and $n=2,3,\dots,N$, write an opening bracket $(_n$ if $f(n)=1$ and a closing bracket $)_n$ if $f(n)=-1$. If $)_{2^m(4k+3)}$ is written, $(_{2^m(4k+1)}$ must have been written before it, and we pair these brackets – except $)_3$ which we pair with $(_a$ where $a$ is the highest power of $2$ less than $N$. All closing brackets up to $N$ can be paired like this, which proves $g(n)\ge0$ for all $n\ge2$.

Suppose $N$ is not of the form $2^s-1$. Consider the leftmost $10$ in its binary representation, e.g.
$$1\underline{10}1101011$$
Change this to $01$ and all bits to its right to $0$:
$$1\underline{01}0000000$$
This number $M$ is smaller than $N$ and is of the form $2^m(4k+1)$. $M$'s bracket is paired with the closing bracket of a number *greater* than $N$ (replace the underlined $01$ in $M$ by $11$). Hence $(_M$ is unpaired and $g(N)>0$.

But going from an opening bracket to its paired closing bracket does not increase the bitsize of the underlying numbers. Thus, if $N=2^s-1$, the opening brackets of all numbers less than $N$ can be successfully paired with the closing brackets of all numbers less than or equal to $N$ using the scheme described in the second paragraph of this answer, which shows $g(N)=0$ in this case.

In summary, $g(n)\ge0$ for all $n\ge2$, and $g(n)=0$ iff $n$ is a Mersenne number.